# GNU Stow: How to stow only selected files/folders?

Tags: stow

Let's assume the following structure of a folder called `scripts`.

```
├── scripts
│   └── .scripts
│       ├── script1
│       ├── script2
│       └── script3
│   └── .config
│       ├── script4
│       ├── script5
│       └── script6
```

When using `stow scripts`, both folders within `scripts` will be symlinked to `~/.scripts` and `~/.config`.

Can I use stow to only symlink `.scripts` without having to remove `.config` from the folder but just basically ignoring it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`stow` has [ignore lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Ignore-Lists) which let you put a file called `.stow-local-ignore` at the top of your source tree. In that, you could put `\.scripts` to have stow ignore that directory and not link it into the target tree.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: if i want to ignore by file extension name, should do like this?
`\*.py` or `\*.md` or `\*.zip`

Answer (score 6):

Let's introduce some [**Stow terminology**](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Terminology):

By default ***Stow*** takes the current directory is your **stow directory**, the name you type as the argument in the command line as the **stow package** and the parent dir as the **target directory**, so when you type:

```
$ stow scripts
```

Without any option your *stow directory* is the current directory, `scripts` is your *package* and the parent of current directory becomes the stow *target directory* where the package will **appear** to be installed(where the symlinks will be created).

You can explicitly inform the **stow directory** and the **package** you want to install in the command line like in the following command:

```
$ stow -d /path_to_scripts_folder/scripts -S .scripts
```

Where the `scripts` here is defined as your *stow directory* and `.scripts` as your *package* in **Stow terminology**.

Optionally you can specify the target directory, that is the directory relative to where your files(symlinks to your files) should be placed:

```
$ stow -d /path/scripts -S .scripts -t ~/
```

To test any of this options you can use the `-n` flag that just simulate the changes without modify your file system:

```
$ stow -n -d /path/scripts -S .scripts -t ~/
```

And if you want to see all actions that should be taken you can add the -v specifying a verbosity level from 0(no `-v` flag) up to 3(`-vvv`):

```
$ stow -n -d /path/scripts -S .scripts -t ~/ -vvv
```

As this options become more and more complex it could be better to write a little shell script to automate your work and give you maximum of flexibility.